# Partial HTML encoder

Tags: html, encoding

Suppose I have text with HTML tags, but where not all characters have been encoded. Are there any tools to intelligently encode while leaving the tags intact? Example:

```
<h2>A'b</h2>
```

to

```
<h2>A&#39;b-</h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could give [HTML Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) a shot... Im not sure if you can configure it to do only this though...

Comment: Thanks. I don't know if it will work yet, but tt looks like it could be useful for other things too